# Is CSS validation no longer relevant?

Tags: css

I've just built my first webpage for years, using HTML5, Bootstrap and jQuery.

When I ran the page through the W3C CSS validator the result returned contained nearly 800 errors (from Bootstrap mostly).

Is CSS validation no longer relevant or is there a more up-to-date css validator that I can use?

Thanks,
N

Comment: Show us the CSS and we can tell you.

Comment: Also depending on the errors? Some might be merely warnings?

Comment: It looks like it :( http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.github.io%2Fbootstrap%2Fexamples%2Fstarter-template.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 4):

It depends what `Profile` you select.

From the amount of errors you received, you probably selected the default `CSS level 2.1`

Try changing this to `CSS level 3`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Curt. I did try direct input of just bootstrap.css (v2.0.2) using CSS3 = 723 errors, 352 warnings. That is what surprised me - that popular framework like bootstrap can fail validation so spectacularly.

Comment: If this is the same bootstrap.css as the one I found on the net, it does have lots of -webkit- and -moz- properties that the validator doesn't recognise, which accounts for most of the errors. But not all of them.

Comment: 785 CSS errors found here with CSS level 3: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.github.com%2Fbootstrap%2Fexamples%2Fhero.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  Bootstrap 2.3.1 still fails WC3's CSS3 validation check with 611 errors.